# Read/Write/Move csv file

Tags: java, html, file, move, read-write

So I'm writing some html code where someone can browse a file and save it(using some java code) in a different location under a new name.  I've attempted a couple of different ways of doing this by browsing a file then reading and writing the file.  However, each time I try to execute the code, it says my function has not been defined.  Below is sample code, where I browse a file and then want to save the file to a new location.

The csv file would have 3 columns and 3000+ rows.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head>
 <title>Java</title>

 <script>
 import java.io.File;

     function ReadWriteCSVFile() {
         File myFile = document.getElementById('fileinput').files;
         myFile.renameTo(new File("/Directory/location/Data.csv"));
     }

</script> 
</head>

<body>

<form>

 Select a file: <input type="file" name="img" id="fileinput">
   <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add to CSV File" onClick="ReadWriteCSVFile()" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I can not seem to figure out why it cannot read my function for the onClick or which method would be best.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: `function` is not a keyword in Java. Did you intend to write Java *code* or JavaSCRIPT?

Comment: Oh, ok.  I intended to write a javascript.  So would I have to to define my script section in a different way?

Comment: Well, the code inside of your Script tags is a mix of Java and Javascript. You declared your function with the `function` keyword, which is Javascript. All of the remainder of the code is in Java. Perhaps if you added `<script type="text/Javascript">` to your script tag, the intellisense would guide you in the right direction. That's assuming you are using Visual Studio. Intellisense is the part of Visual Studio that shows errors in your code or makes recommendations. Sometimes it only works if you tell it what code you are trying to write, such as by adding the `type` to your script tag.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing Java and JavaScript, which does not work. Java the compiled language is not JavaScript. You cannot call a Java Method like that. To accomplish what you're trying to do, you will need to create a Java Applet.

[Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html)